# Rails: redirect_to don`t redirect to subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I try to redirect user to custom domain. Code below:

```
def redirector
    user = User.find(1)
    redirect_to posts_path(:subdomain => user.domain)
end
```

But user will redirected to host domain (site.com) without subdomain. Dev log:

```
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = '1' LIMIT 1
Redirected to site.com/posts
```

Using Rails 4.1.4 with ruby 2.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to additionally specify the `tld_length`.

More information at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for

Comment: Thanks, it work: redirect_to url_for(controller: "posts", action: "index", subdomain: user.domain)